# MS Access help needed forming a specific report

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a column for agent names and a column for each of the skills those agents could possibly have. Each skill the agent is assigned shows a 1 in the field under that skill.

Columns look like this:

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  Name   | 'Skill1' | 'Skill2' | 'Skill3' |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| John    |        1 |          |        1 |
| Sam     |        1 |        1 |          |
| Roberta |        1 |          |        1 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I would like to make a query that returns a list of all **agent names** that have a 1 for each particular skill. The query would return something like this:

```
+-----------+
| Skill 1   |
+-----------+
| John      |
| Sam       |
| Roberta   |
+-----------+
```

Additionally I would like to be able to query a single name and retrieve all skills that agent has (all rows the Name column has a 1 in) like this:

```
+-----------+
|  John     |
+-----------+
| Skill 1   |
| Skill 3   |
+-----------+
```

I've done this in Excel using an index but I'm new to Access and not sure how to complete this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read up on _normalising_ data. Then implement this, and you can use simple select queries to pull the requested results.

Comment: Access is a relational database management system (RDBMS). It is very different from Excel. If you want to use it efficiently, you must understand and follow some design rules. As @Gustav suggested, you should search for 'database normalisation', spend some time learning this, and properly design your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons that you are finding this task difficult is because your database is not [normalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and so due to the way that your database is structured, you are working against MS Access, not with it.

Consequently, whilst a solution is still possible with the current data, the resulting queries will be painful to construct and will either be full of multiple messy `iif` statements, or several `union` queries performing the same operations over & over again, one for each 'skill'.

Then, if you every wish to add another Skill to the database, all of your queries have to be rewritten!

Whereas, if your database was *normalised* (as Gustav has suggested in the comments), the task would be a simple one-liner; and what's more, if you add a new skill later on, your queries will automatically output the results as if the skill had always been there.

---

Your data has a **many-to-many relationship**: an agent may have many skills, and a skill may be known by many agents.

As such, the most appropriate way to represent this relationship is using a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Hence, you would have a table of Agents such as:

#### tblAgents

```
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID  | FirstName | LastName |    DOB     |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+
|   1 | John      | Smith    | 1970-01-01 |
| ... | ...       | ...      | ...        |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+
```

This would only contain information unique to each agent, i.e. minimising the repeated information between records in the table.

You would then have a table of possible Skills, such as:

#### tblSkills

```
+-----+---------+---------------------+
| ID  |  Name   |     Description     |
+-----+---------+---------------------+
|   1 | Skill 1 | Skill 1 Description |
|   2 | Skill 2 | Skill 2 Description |
| ... | ...     | ...                 |
+-----+---------+---------------------+
```

Finally, you would have a junction table linking Agents to Skills, e.g.:

#### tblAgentSkills

```
+----+----------+----------+
| ID | Agent_ID | Skill_ID |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |        2 |
|  3 |        2 |        1 |
|  4 |        3 |        2 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

---

Now, say you want to find out which agents have `Skill 1`, the query is simple:

```sql
select Agent_ID from tblAgentSkills where Skill_ID = 1
```

What if you want to find out the skills known by an agent? Equally as simple:

```sql
select Skill_ID from tblAgentSkills where Agent_ID = 1
```

Of course, these queries will merely return the `ID` fields as present in the junction table - but since the ID **uniquely identifies** a record in the `tblAgents` or `tblSkills` tables, such ID is all you need to retrieve any other required information:

```sql
select 
    tblAgents.FirstName, 
    tblAgents.LastName
from 
    tblAgentSkills inner join tblAgents on 
    tblAgentSkills.AgentID = tblAgents.ID
where 
    tblAgentSkills.Skill_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all agents with skill1, open the query designer and create the following query:
[image]

this will generate the following sql

SELECT Skills.AgentName
FROM Skills
WHERE (((Skills.Skill1)=1));

If you adjust the names you can also paste this query into the sql pane of the designer to get the query you want.
To get all the skills an agent has I chose a parameterized query.  Open the query designer and create a new query:
[image]

When you run this query it will ask you for the name of the agent.  Make sure to type the agent name exactly.  Here is the resulting sql:

SELECT Skills.AgentName, Skills.Skill1, Skills.Skill2, Skills.Skill3
FROM Skills
WHERE (((Skills.AgentName)=[Agent]));

If you continue working with this query I would improve the table design by breaking your table into a skills table, agents table, skills&agents table.  Then link the skills and agents tables to the skills&agents table in a many to many relationship.  The query to get all an agents skills would then look like this in the designer:

[image]